# Odoo 10.0 Name_search domain example

Tags: python, odoo-10

I need to use many2one `product_id` field in my one2many field `product_lines` and products should be filtered based on `page_no`.

Model1 contains product_lines(o2m : model2-model1_id) and page_no

```
class model1(models.Model):
    _name = "model1"

    ....
    page_no = fields.Integer('Page No.')
    ...
    product_lines = fields.One2many('model2', 'model1_id', 'Product lines')
```

model2 contains product_id and model1_id(m2o : model1)

```
class model2(models.Model):
    _name = "model2"

    model1_id = fields.Many2one('model1')
    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product')
```

in my xml for form view of model1 is

```
    <field name="product_lines"  >
        <tree editable="bottom" name="petan_nos">
            <field name="model1_id" invisible="1" />
            <field name="product_id" domain="[('page_no', '=', model1_id.page_no)]" />
        </tree>
    </field>
```

And this is how I ma getting error front end error `Uncaught Error: AttributeError: object has no attribute 'page_no'` no error stack on terminal.

How to handle this and use field of relational fields in domain so I can use name_search and modify the behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you want please explain in details?

Comment: means that when open page so automatic by-default search selected?

Comment: While creating product_lines, in the product field I want  only those products with the same page_no which I have added in model1 form.....

Comment: Paste python code also.

Comment: @KbiR I edited my question and added python code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inherit `product.product` and add field `page_no`.

```
_inherit='product.product'

page_no = fields.Char('Page_no')
```

And also define `page_no` in `model2`

```
class model2(models.Model):
_name = "model2"

model1_id = fields.Many2one('model1')
product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product')
page_no = fields.Char('Page_no')
```

**In xml**

```
<field name="product_lines"  >
    <tree editable="bottom" name="petan_nos">
        <field name="page_no" />
        <field name="model1_id" invisible="1" />
        <field name="product_id" domain="[('page_no', '=', page_no)]" />
    </tree>
</field>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for answer@kbir ... Does that mean i can't use fields of relational field in domain in Odoo 10?

Comment: Well, this is a possible way, but I'm in search of direct use of relational field.... if somehow is possible.... else I can accept the answer.

Comment: I don't think so you can use relational field directly in domain search..

Comment: Accepting your answer